# Is it possible to have a vscode panel on the top and bottom?

Tags: visual-studio-code

so for my current coding configuration I use a vertical monitor and I despise using the side panels for vscode so I only use the bottom one and would also like to use a top one, however, it seems in the settings options and the view options that I can't split this panel and have a workspace panel on top of my code editor and one at the bottom (sandwiching my code editor). Is there some sort of workaround or additional setting where I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Visual Studio Code at the time of this writing (version 1.81) does not support having two panels open at the same time. It can only "be moved to the left or right for more vertical space."<sup>[1](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_basic-layout:%7E:text=moved%20to%20the%20left%20or%20right%20for%20more%20vertical%20space.)</sup>

However, you can split the different tabs of an active panel. For example, If I wanted more vertical space, I could move the panel to the right and split it between the debug console and the terminal:

[image: click and drag a panel member to split the panel]

Unfortunately, in your case, this may not leave much horizontal space left to the editor groups. You may find that you're most comfortable leaving the panel at the bottom and splitting it horizontally.